# Domain of attraction geometric distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

How is it possible to prove that the geometric distribution
$F(k)= 1−(1−p)^{k}, k \in \mathbb{N}$ has no extreme value distribution?

Comment: Have you  tried to use differentiation?

Comment: Do you know the test for convergence of the maximum? What do you know?